# Deploying a manifest app package for microsoft teams (Something Went wrong)

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, azure-qna-maker

https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app/wiki/Deployment-guide
This is the resource I used to create my service.
I've run through the process multiple times to make sure I didn't miss anything
but now I've hit a wall of "something went wrong". No error codes.
I'm not sure how to proceed since "you don't know what you don't know"

Thank you in advance for any guidance,

Jamie

Here is my code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "---------",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.faqplus",
  "developer": {
    "name": "<<Jamie P>>",
    "websiteUrl": "https://emergent360.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://emergent360.com/rosieprivacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://emergent360.com/rosieterms"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "EmergentRosie"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "A friendly QnA bot that answers questions and connects you to experts.",
    "full": "A friendly question and answer bot that answers commonly asked questions. If it can't answer, it will put you in touch with an expert as soon as they are available."
  },
  "accentColor": "#64A2CC",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "--------",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "team"
      ],
      "commandLists": [
        {
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ],
            "commands": [
                {
                    "title": "Take a tour",
                    "description": "Tour of key features"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Ask an expert",
                    "description": "Connect with an expert"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Share feedback",
                    "description": "Send feedback"
                }
            ]
        }
      ],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "help",
      "name": "Help",
      "contentUrl": "https://emergentrosie.azurewebsites.net/help?theme={theme}",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "emergentrosie.azurewebsites.net"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried installing your manifest and it just loads fine for me. Could you please add the relevant id's and try to install it? Please share a screenshot of the error you see.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost always a result of not actually activating the Teams channel within your bot. Got to your `Bot Service > Channels > Teams` and make sure it is activated. Once you have done that, you should be able to deploy your bot on teams channel without issue.

Comment: I looked over my setup and I can't seem to find a way to connect the provided code to the bot service. The deployment guide I used had me create two separate app services, one for enduser and the other for admins (config). Where do I associate the bot service with the manifest?